# Ralink rt5390 driver problem

Tags: ralink, patch

I am a new linux user. I am trying to set up my ralink drivers.

I am following the steps from another forum
which are:

1. download driver: http://www.mediatek.com/_en/07_downloads/01-1_windowsDetail.php?sn=5001
2. `tar -xvf /home/ukbeast/USERNAME/Downloads
   /2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO_v2.bz2.bz2`
3. `cd 2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO`
4. download patch: http://gridlox.net/diff/rt5592sta_fix_64bit_3.8.patch
5. `patch -p1 < rt5592sta_fix_64bit_3.8.patch` (if asks for directory point it to pci_main_dev.c)
6. make sure /os/linux/config.mk reads HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=y
7. `make`
8. `sudo make install`
9. `modprobe rt5390sta`

I am getting stuck on step 5. When I enter `patch -p1 < rt5592sta_fix_64bit_3.8.patch` into the terminal I am getting "no such file or directory" as a response.

I do not know how to point it to pci_main>dev.c?

Any help on how to point it there would be much appreciated.

Comment: Silly question probably, but have you saved the patch file to the correct folder (i.e. 2011_1007....)? I just went through the steps from scratch again and it worked correctly, and I don't remember having any problems with the patch the first time around either (I used this same driver to get my wireless working after upgrading to 13) Perhaps try going to the folder and for step 4 using `curl -O  http://gridlox.net/diff/rt5592sta_fix_64bit_3.8.patch` ?

Comment: ok so I got past step 5 using what you said. My patch was in the wrong folder. now i am stuck on #9. When I run modprobe rt5390 it returns error: could not insert: operation not permitted. any idea on how to get past that. Thanks again for your help i really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

The file `rt5592sta_fix_64bit_3.8.patch` must be in the same location as your `Makefile` (base dir of the driver source). Also, you will require `sudo` for step 7.

Comment: Why would you require `sudo` for `make`?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried placing the downloaded .patch file inside 2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO directory and then run the command from inside that directory? I did that on Ubuntu 13.04 and it has worked.

Comment: Could you be more descriptive? The exacts commands will be helpful.